# Can't find class of postgresql driver

Tags: java, postgresql, hikaricp

I'm trying to use HikariCP library for PostgreSQL connection pools in Java. I am using Maven, and I'm getting this error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver`.

I have tried using different versions of the PostgreSQL driver, but none have worked to my advantage. (I have done more, but I've been faced with this problem, that I have not taken note of)

`org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource`, `org.postgresql.Driver` and `com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDataSource` still produce this error, even though it is said in the [HikariCP guide](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP#popular-datasource-class-names) to use either the first or third. The second I found from research.

### My maven:

```xml
(...)
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.12.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

### What I'm using to produce this error:

```java
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Failed to load.");
        }

        HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig("database.properties");
        ds = new HikariDataSource(config);
```

(The constructor `HikariDataSource(config);` produces this error aswell)

I believe the reason why this is happening is that the driver is not being made into the classpath - however, all efforts I have tried can't seem to do this. This problem of the driver not being in the final jar (to my belief):
[image: org.postgresql is not found in final jar].

### Actual error:

```
[20:16:35 WARN]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:152)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:100)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at me.test.kitpvp.Kitpvp.onEnable(Kitpvp.java:43)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:264)
[20:16:35 WARN]:        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.enablePlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:337)
(...)
[20:16:35 INFO]: Failed to load.
[20:16:35 WARN]: 74 [Server thread] INFO com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
```

*Edits*

- Adding `<scope>compile</scope>` produced same results - did not work.

Comment: Did you tried <scope>complie</scope> for the postgres depency in pom.xml?

Comment: @StijnLeenknegt <scope>compile</scope> in my pom.xml had the same result as without it - thanks for the fast response nevertheless.

Comment: https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.5/bundle , try add the <type> tag...

Comment: That has made the `org.postgresql:postgresql:bundle:42.2.5` in the Maven tab in IntelliJ have a red line with the error `Problems: Unresolved dependency: 'org.postgresql:postgresql:bundle:42.2.5'` - I don't know how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a filter to include the driver artifact in the shaded JAR:

```
<configuration>
   <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
   <filters>
       <filter>
           <artifact>org.postgresql:postgresql</artifact>
           <includes>
               <include>**</include>
           </includes>
       </filter>
   </filters>
```

For more details: [Selecting Contents for Uber JAR](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html).

The issue occurs due to the (unfiltered) `<minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>` configuration in your POM, and the fact that the driver class is not used at compile time.

maven-shade-plugin on [`minimizeJar`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/shade-mojo.html#minimizeJar):

> When true, dependencies will be stripped down on the class level to only the transitive hull required for the artifact.